# Can a non-macroscopic object have mass?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, mass, decoherence

According to this [resource from John Boccio](https://tinyurl.com/johnboccio):

> Consider a body at rest on surface of Earth. Imagine that it shifts
> about vertically ever so slightly. Because it has done so, it has
> moved to a slightly higher or lower elevation, and so it has shifted
> its gravitational potential energy which depends on height. This will
> cause factor Et / ħ, to fluctuate. If the shifting about is random,
> the resulting fluctuation in this factor will wipe out the quantum
> superposition. Some Numbers: If a mass M shifts its elevation by
> height H , its gravitational potential energy has changed by MgH ,
> where g is acceleration due to gravity. Then, after a time
>
> $$t = \frac{ħ}{MgH}$$
>
> the factors will have altered enough to cause a significant
> fluctuation. If mass M is, say 100 kilograms, and H is only of the
> order of the dimensions of single atom, say 10−10m , then this
> fluctuation occurs in extraordinarily short time of 10−27 seconds!

It seems to imply that quantum objects can have mass, at least mathematically. I would take this to mean even a fundamental unit as a single atom.  It is possible then for very small objects to have mass such as 100 kg or is it referring to the decoherence of macroscopic objects made up of many billions of atoms?

Comment: What is meant here is a macroscopic object? Unfortunately things would only work this way if the world wasn't relativistic and if completely rigid objects would exist. Neither is the case, so whatever you are hearing about "the quantum behavior of large objects" at this level is merely an overextrapolation of microscopic physics. The actual quantum mechanical behavior of a non-rigid macroscopic body is given by its phonon spectrum, which can indeed be measured and it does not happen on these ridiculous time scales.

Answer (score 0):

The document refers to a 100kg mass without specifying what kind of system he's discussing. Nor does it give any references to any other literature for further explanation. I would guess that the 100kg mass is supposed to be a macroscopic object and that this document is giving a mangled report of some decoherence model, but it's difficult to tell and I don't think working it out is a good use of anyone's time.

There is plenty of material available on decoherence for free from physicists who use references correctly and explain what they're discussing properly, e.g.

https://arxiv.org/abs/1911.06282

I suggest reading this kind of material instead.